# UPDATE query is slow in combination with RETURNING INTO clause

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have update query which returns updated rows ID. Execution time of query is about 90 seconds. When i remove Returning clause, then execution time is 1ms.
Table update_table has 39000 rows.
Query updates 0 rows in this case. When updates 3 rows- execution time is same.

```
DECLARE
  type intTable IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
  idCol intTable;
BEGIN
UPDATE 
  update_table
            SET  
            prop1 = 3, prop2 = NULL
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT null FROM update_table f 
                    INNER JOIN rel_table1 u ON f.ID= u.ID
                    INNER JOIN rel_table2 VP ON f.another_ID = VP.another_ID
                WHERE (u.prop1 = 3) 
                    AND VP.prop1 = 1
                    AND (u.prop2 = 75)
                    AND f.ID = update_table.ID
            )
         ReTURNING ID BULK COLLECT INTO idCol;
.
.
.
  END;
```

Why returning clause slows down query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good part of using Oracle is knowing what is "supposed" to happen and what isn't.

Adding a `RETURNING INTO` clause is not "supposed" to make your update run more slowly.  When something happens that isn't supposed to happen, check Oracle's support site to see whether it is a known bug.

In your case, it looks like you are encountering:

> Bug 27131648 - SUB OPTIMAL PLAN ON UPDATE STATEMENT WITH RETURNING INTO

I am not sure if there is a patch, but there is a simple workaround: use the `UNNEST` hint.  In your case, that would be:

```
UPDATE 
  update_table
            SET  
            prop1 = 3, prop2 = NULL
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT /*+ UNNEST */ null FROM update_table f 
                    INNER JOIN rel_table1 u ON f.ID= u.ID
                    INNER JOIN rel_table2 VP ON f.another_ID = VP.another_ID
                WHERE (u.prop1 = 3) 
                    AND VP.prop1 = 1
                    AND (u.prop2 = 75)
                    AND f.ID = update_table.ID
            )
         ReTURNING ID BULK COLLECT INTO idCol;
```

Comment: This seems to be a correct answer. I can observe a change in execution plan containing a `FILTER` with nested subquery after adding the `RETURNING` clause. The `UNNEST` hint works returning the plan back to the former version.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting it into two parts, first `BULK COLLECT` and next `FORALL` collected ID's, both extremely fast and you'll keep being able to further reference updated ID's from `idCol`.

```
DECLARE
  type intTable IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
  idCol intTable;
BEGIN
    SELECT f.id 
      BULK COLLECT INTO idCol
      FROM update_table f 
     INNER JOIN rel_table1 u ON f.ID= u.ID
     INNER JOIN rel_table2 VP ON f.another_ID = VP.another_ID
     WHERE (u.prop1 = 3) 
         AND VP.prop1 = 1
         AND (u.prop2 = 75);

    FORALL indx IN 1..idCol.COUNT
        UPDATE update_table
           SET prop1 = 3, prop2 = NULL
         WHERE id = idCol(indx);

.
.
.
END;
```

I hope I helped!